# How do I restore normal colorscheme?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, color

Upon launching vim, if I enter `colorscheme` the output is `default`. If I enter `colorscheme default` the colorscheme changes. If I change the colorscheme from the default to any other colorscheme and then enter `colorscheme default` the behavior is the same as before. The only way I know of to restore the original colorscheme is to exit vim and relaunch it. This is really only an issue with the Goyo plugin as it alters the colorscheme temporarily, breaking it. I don't know what the cause of this behavior is or why the colorscheme fails to return to normal.

Can anyone explain this or provide a solution to restore the original colorscheme?

Comment: Note that I tried initializing vim with `vim -u NONE` and when I turned syntax on it was displayed with the same "default" scheme that appears once the colorscheme has been changed under usual conditions.

Comment: Try `set bg=dark` after colorscheme default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `colorscheme default` vim tries to detect background (whether it is dark or light) and apply dark or light syntax highlighting.

Very often it detects background as light. Usually `set background=dark` or `set background=light` depending on what is your terminal background color should work to fix the colors.

```
colorscheme default
set background=dark
```

Comment: That was so simple. Thanks, this did correct the color palette.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of Vim earlier than 8.2.1693, you may be experiencing [the effects of a bug in Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4405).

Prior to [the fix](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/05eb5b9cae123b138bbd23cc77e50657ece6b4ad), there was no general solution for this issue. The only solution was to go through and reset all the colours to what they should be, one-by-one.

[There is some background to the problem here](http://peterodding.com/code/vim/colorscheme-switcher/#known_problems), by the author of the Colorscheme Switcher plugin, which attempted a workaround.

If for some reason you are unable to upgrade Vim, you can set up a [`ColorScheme`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#ColorScheme) autocommand that fixes up the specific colours that are set incorrectly after the colorscheme is changed.

```
augroup FixColorScheme
  autocmd!
  autocmd ColorScheme default call FixColours()
augroup END

function! FixColors abort
  " Enter :hilight commands to fix incorrect colours here
endfunction
```

Comment: I would argue about "isn't designed to support" -- vim is fine to switch colorschemes on the fly. There were issues with linked highlight groups to persist and leak into other colorschemes, but it was fixed quite a time ago. The issue is with default colorscheme that relies on background detection(which fails more than not).

Comment: @MaximKim Ah, I didn't realise it had been fixed. Last time I tried it (admittedly a while ago, it didn't work.) Thanks for the correction: you should post an answer!

Comment: @MaximKim "it was fixed" <- By you!!

Comment: I put some efforts to make it happen, indeed :)